# Copy arrays-vectors

Tags: c++

This might be too basic, but I would like to ask. I have my code in Java that copies the `start` array to `newStart` and assigns the last element to another array.

```
int[] newStart= Arrays.copyOf(start, start.length + 1);
newStart[start.length] = array[i];
```

I converted it to my C++ version with vectors as:

```
vector<int> newStart(5);   //Doesnt have to be 5, sth not known  
newStart.insert(newStart.end(), start.begin(), start.end());
newStart[start.size()] = array[i];
```

However, my code doesn't do what I require. That adds the vector one to the other's end, and makes new assignments accordingly. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Erm, does that Java code even work? (anyway: `vector<int> newStart(start); newStart.push_back(array[i);`)

Comment: You say "latest element to another array" but I only see one array here called `newStart`.

Comment: You didn't say what your code does or does not do and I missed the completely wrong initialization of `newStart` to given size. That is equivalent to `resize`, not `reserve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ vectors don't auto-resize on element access (through `operator[]` nor `at` method). Replace the last line with either

```
newStart.push_back(array[i]);
```

or

```
newStart.resize(start.size() + 1);
newStart[start.size()] = array[i];
```

(the former being more efficient, because it does not default-initialize the element first)

I believe Java arrays don't auto-resize either, so I wouldn't expect the Java code to work either (but it will give exception while the C++ code will make daemons fly out of your nose or whatever else nasty the compiler will think of).

---

Edit: Reading the question again, the code there is actually defined, but the more wrong.

```
vector<int> newStart(5);   //Doesnt have to be 5, sth not known
```

This statement actually creates a vector that contains 5 (or whatever) default initialized elements, which in case of `int` is 0. So now you have

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

For sake of example let's say `start` contains `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`.

```
newStart.insert(newStart.end(), start.begin(), start.end());
```

`vector::insert` adds new elements extending the array and moving the following elements as necessary. The insert is before `end`, so it will append to the vector, resulting in:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

I don't think this is what you wanted. It looks like you wanted a copy of start. Which you'd simply create by copy constructing: `vector<int> newStart(start)`.

```
newStart[start.size()] = array[i];
```

Now `newStart` has the initial 5 zeroes and the elements from `start`, so it's size is `start.size() + 5` and therefore it does have index `start.size()`. It is the 5<sup>th</sup> element from end. So per above example, this will modify the vector to:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7}
                      ^
```

To append start[0] to the end, use `push_back` as per above.

---

Also remember, that Java arrays are reference types, where assignment just shares reference to the same array, but C++ vectors are value types where the content is copied on assignment.

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood, but as far as i know the vectors in c++ do auto-resize. I use it a lot, you can use reserve to create an initial reserved memory area.

Comment: @pwny This is exactly what this answer says.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get it, this answer wasn't really well formulated.. my bad

Comment: @pwny Read the *full answer* again, and take into account the code in the question, then it should become clear that “don’t auto-resize” applies to the usage via `operator[]`, not `push_back` (which obviously resizes, giving its name; but it doesn’t *auto*-resize).

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're absolutely right but I would still edit the answer to "Don't auto-resize through operator[]"

Comment: Hm, the code was actually much more wrong than I originally noticed. Added a lot more description.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the mixing of Java and C++.  Hopefully one of the explinations below will help.

If you're in C++, vector has an overloaded [operator=](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) so you can just type

`newvector = oldvector;`

and it will copy.

If you're in java, you can use the [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28java.util.Collection%29) ex:

`Vector v2 = new Vector(v1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = start.begin() ; it != start.end(); ++it) {
     newStart.push_back (*it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) algorithm  and [back_inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/) iterator.

Sample code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> src;
  std::vector<int> dest;

  std::copy(src.begin(),src.end(),back_inserter(dest));
}
```